# How do I create backtick in backticks?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I want to write backtick inside backtick. (es6)

How do you create backtick in backtick ?

```
const apple = 'apple';
const grape = 'grape';
const money1 = 2000;
const money2 = 1000;


// before
console.log(`${apple} = ${grape === 'grape' ? '(' + money1 + ')' : '(' + money2 + ')'`;

// after  <-- I want
console.log(`${apple} = ${grape === 'grape' ? \`(${money1})\` : \`(${money2})\`}`;
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you want the actual log message to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the backslashes:

```js
const apple = 'apple';
const grape = 'grape';
const money1 = 2000;
const money2 = 1000;

console.log(`${apple} = ${grape === 'grape' ? `(${money1})` : `(${money2})`}`);
```

If you were asking about printing a literal backpack in a template string, then just use a backslash normally.

```js
console.log(`\``);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literaly:  "to put a backtick in backticks"  sounds like how to put a literal backtick into a string.  To do that, escape it.

Escape it with a backslash.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Description

```
`\``
```

```js
console.log(`\``)
```

But what you actually are trying to do is not so complex.  The JavaScript syntax allows for nesting backticks within ${} without escaping them.

```js
console.log(`Hello ${`world`}, ${`nesting ${`works too`}`}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that your example is partially hypothetical, but there's a much simpler approach to your example that avoids the need for nested template literals:

```js
const apple = 'apple';
const grape = 'grape';
const money1 = 2000;
const money2 = 1000;


console.log(`${apple} = (${grape === 'grape' ? money1 : money2})`);
```